# Добавить к строке её порядковый номер C#

Tags: c#, массивы, winforms

Только недавно начал изучать C#, столкнулся с некоторыми трудностями.

Есть список строковых значений, который нужно вывести на экран в элемент listbox.
Также есть массив, в который эти строки добавляются, после чего выводятся на экран.

В программе есть два класса - абстрактный и производный. В абстрактном классе есть два метода:
первый содержит список всех строковых значений, а второй добавляет все эти значения в массив и выводит их на экран. В производном классе массив сортируется.

Мне необходимо, чтобы **каждой строке в массиве присваивался свой порядковый номер и выводился вместе со значением этой строки**.
Реализовать это необходимо с помощью отдельного метода в абстрактном классе, который будет возвращать нумерованный список элементов.

Как можно реализовать данную функцию? Уже многое перепробовал, но так и не нашел решение.
Код абстрактного класса и методов прилагаю.

```
abstract public class BaseNotes //Базовый класс со списком элементов
{
    protected ArrayList notes = new ArrayList(); //Создаем новый защищенный от изменения список элементов notes

    //Открытые методы класса
    //метод заполнения массива строк (конструктор класса)
    public BaseNotes()
    {
        notes.Add("История");
        notes.Add("Философия");
        notes.Add("Иностранный язык");
        notes.Add("Экономическая теория");
        notes.Add("Математика");
    }

    //Метод объединения значений списка в массив
    public string[] GetMyList()
    {
        string[] ArrStr = new string[notes.Count]; //Создание массива размеров с количестом элементов
        notes.CopyTo(ArrStr); //Копирование всех строк в новый массив
        return ArrStr; //Возврат значений массива
    }
}
```

Comment: Если список может меняться, то дёргать на каждое изменение перенумерацию как-то глупо, да? Есть вариант поменять парадигму: вместо того, чтобы создавать абстрактный тип данных поддерживающий нумерацию - можно создать класс для отображения любого списка с нумерацией. Типа NumberedFormatter -- и отпадает сама необходимость в том, чтобы держать какие-то методы для нумерации, либо не держать методы, но постоянно пересчитывать внутри эту самую нумерацию. А так у вас нет ни структуры для хранения нумерации, да и вывод вы не написали -- а как дойдёте до конкретики сразу увидите ошибку проектирования.

Comment: @AK Да, согласен, это глупо, постоянно передергивать значения. Но, к сожалению, того требует задание - именно сделать метод для пересчета каждый раз, когда добавляются или удаляются новые значения. Неудобно, конечно

Comment: окей, замечание принято: считаем задачу учебной и не обращаем внимания на подобные мелочи. Тогда просто покажите какая сигнатура должна быть у этого метода: `второй добавляет все эти значения в массив и выводит их на экран` (как по мне здесь ещё одна ошибка проектирования, как минимум нарушен SPR: и расчёт и вывод, а также я не уверен, что нужно показывать сразу миллион элементов, надо показать элементы "10 штук начиная с 1200", а это уже совсем иная сигнатура, а то и два разных вывода в довесок к одному расчёту)

Comment: @AK совершенно прав (только SRP, а не SPR) :) Я дополнил в ответ вариант в возвращением массива, если уж так надо.

Comment: Удалось разобраться? Был ли полезен мой ответ? Если нет, до давайте разбираться, почему, или давайте я его удалю. Если да, то можете пометить его галочкой.

Comment: @aepot да, всё удалось, спасибо Вам большое! И Вам, @A K, тоже. Все наконец получилось. Галочкой пометил. Еще раз, огромная Вам благодарность!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не используйте `ArrayList`, `Array` и другие классы из `System.Collections`, это всего-лишь наследие древнего шарпа, используйте обобщенные коллекции из `System.Collections.Generic`.

Реализовать можно то что вам надо с помощью энумератора, и не придется клонировать массив, что само по себе - неэффективное занятие.

```cs
abstract public class BaseNotes
{
    protected List<string> notes = new List<string>();

    public BaseNotes()
    {
        notes.Add("История");
        notes.Add("Философия");
        notes.Add("Иностранный язык");
        notes.Add("Экономическая теория");
        notes.Add("Математика");
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> EnumerateNotes()
    {
        int i = 1;
        // здесь именно foreach, а не for, потому что он защищен от случаев, когда список будет изменен во время энумерации
        // будет выброшено исключение, что в принципе правильно и защитит разработчика от лишних ошибок
        foreach (string note in notes)
        {
            yield return $"{i++}. {note}";
        }
    }
}

public class Notes : BaseNotes
{

}

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Notes notes = new Notes();
        foreach (string note in notes.EnumerateNotes())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(note);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
1. История
2. Философия
3. Иностранный язык
4. Экономическая теория
5. Математика
```

---

Либо можно более элегантно написать метод `EnumerateNotes()` с помощью `Linq`

```cs
public IEnumerable<string> EnumerateNotes()
{
    return notes.Select((note, i) => $"{i + 1}. {note}");
}
```

Если вам принципиально вернуть массив строк, то можете так

```cs
public string[] GetNotes()
{
    return notes.Select((note, i) => $"{i + 1}. {note}").ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Как вариант для `EnumerateNotes()` предложу использовать перегрузку `Select` с индексом элемента в коллекции: `notes.Select((note, i) => $"{i+1}. {note}");`

Comment: @AndreiKhotko век живи - век учись. Спасибо, исправил.